# Replacing a specific spaces with dashes

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Trying to replace specific spaces with dashes and lowercase the string

e.g.

```
"1.0 Domain - sub & domain"

"1.0-Domain-sub&domain"
```

Tried

```
str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
-> 1.0-domain---sub-&-domain
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could capture either `-` or `&` between optional whitespace chars and replace that with only the captured char, or else match 1 or more whitespace chars to be replaced with an empty string using the [replacer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

```js
let str = "1.0 Domain - sub & domain";

str = str.replace(/\s*([&-])\s*|\s+/g, (m, g1) => g1 ? g1 : '-').toLowerCase();

console.log(str)
```